# ReactJS: pass data through 3 components

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm trying to pass data through 3 components within the hierarchy (Parent-Child-Child2):

Parent-class:

```
 class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
       this.handleOperation = this.handleOperation.bind(this);
   }

   handleOperation = (value) => {
      // some actions
   };

render() {
       return (
           <div className={styles}>
               <Child valueChild={this.handleOperation()}/>
           </div>
             );
        }
 }
```

Child1:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange =(value) => {
    this.props.valueChild(value);
};

render() {
    return (
          <div>
              <Child2 childValue2 = {this.handleChange} />
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Child2:

```
 class Child2 extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange =(event) => {
    this.props.childValue2(event.target.value);
};

 render() {
      return (
                <div>
                   <input type="button" onClick={this.handleChange} value="defaultValue" />
               </div>
              );
         }
  }
```

Code compiling successfully, but when I click on input-field (to pass value to Parent), I receive the following error:

[image: error]

Comment: Its happening because of this `<Child valueChild={this.handleOperation()}/>` it should be `<Child valueChild={this.handleOperation}/>` in your parent. Never try to drill. Use `context` or `redux` for state management

Comment: valueChild={this.handleOperation()} remove invocking brackets